# ModSecurity on Apache 2.2 in EC2 - HTTP Status 413 messages dropped

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, mod-security

Hi I am running Mod_Security on Ubuntu instances in EC2 behind an Elastic Loadbalancer. The app is a Ruby App.

I have set

```
SecRequestBodyLimit 293601280
```

When I upload files below that size, they are processed as expected. When I exceed the size limit above I get mixed results.

Mod Security logs that it sent a 413, Request Entity too Large, to the client.
However at the client occasionally I see the 413 reported in various developer tools, more often it is a `net::Error-Disconnect`.

In the end my goal is to trap the 413 in code and report to the end user they have exceeded the file size.

This problem is HTTPS connection so TCPDump/Wireshark are little help.
Disabling ModSecurity allows files of any size to upload.

Any ideas?